# Cannot resolve method 'add(int, com.example.**.beatle.app.MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, import

```
package com.example.**.beatle.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity   {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(savedInstanceState==null)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        String[] forecastArray = {"Today-Sunny-88/63", "Tommorrow-windy-88/94", "wed-aloo-alooo"};
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_main, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
        return rootView;

    }
}}
```

> **Messages Gradle Build**
>       Error:(27, 59) error: no suitable method found for         add(int,PlaceholderFragment)
>       method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
>       method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; PlaceholderFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)
>       Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to      get full output
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` instead of `import android.app.Fragment;`

Comment: I have changed it now it looks like :import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater; Gererating errors :Error:(19, 35) error: cannot find symbol class FragmentActivity Error:(21, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertypeError:(23, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super Error:(24, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)  Error:(27, 13) error: cannot find symbol method getSupportFragmentManager() Error:(32, 5), and many more errors , I am newbie can you please help

Comment: Or use     getFragmentManager() instead of  
     getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are using `FragmentActivity` and `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Therefore, `PlaceholderFragment` needs to inherit from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, not `android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Doing so , generates various errors like:'Error:(19, 35) error: cannot find symbol class FragmentActivity   Error:(21, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype   Error:(23, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super  Error:(24, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int) Error:(27, 13) error: cannot find symbol method getSupportFragmentManager()  Error:(32, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype  Error:(35, 9) error: cannot find symbol method getMenuInflater() Error:(51, 16) error: cannot find symbol variable supe

Comment: @sesy: Sorry, but your comment did not work. You are welcome to ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you show your revised code and provide details of whatever errors you see.

Comment: @CommonWare: I have done what you have said before also It generated more errors that's why i removed it can u suggest more answers

Comment: @sesy: Apparently you deleted your `import` for `FragmentActivity` for some reason. I did not suggest that in my answer, and I have no idea why you did that. I suggest that you undo your change, re-read my answer, and make the change that I suggested.

Comment: Thanks, This solved my issue as well. First time working with fragments, new to mobile dev. Thank you

Comment: Automagics has its problem, my IDE resolves it to `android.app.fragment` instead of the support one.

Comment: I had this problem aso, but I was doing 

`FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();`

instead of the support one. So check you are doing 

`FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

instead of

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

All over in the project.

Also, use support library for FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction.

Answer (score 3):

If you use **AndroidX** of Andorid Jetpack, then use,

```
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```

instead of,

```
import android.app.Fragment;
// or
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```